# describing the degree of unexpectedness of a change in a person's behavior

Tags: phrase-request

> By the end of this school year, he has become especially active in
>   different science projects - **a change that was really hard to
>   expect** in him in the very beginning.

Is "a change that was really hard to expect" good English?

Should it be better like:

1) a change that was really hard to be expected

2) a change that was really difficult to expect

3) a change that was really difficult to be expected

4) a change that was not to expect

5) a change that was not to be expected

6) a change that was barely to be expected

7) a change that was hardly to be expected

or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical collocations are

> It was a change wholly unexpected.
>
> The change was entirely unexpected.

If you change "unexpected" to "expected" you can use "hardly" as you have done:

> The change was hardly (to be) expected.